# Salesforce: How to only render apex if current user has permission to update current record. Record level security

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, user-permissions

I'm trying to fix my code posted for this question [VisualForce: convert carriage returns to html line-breaks in a long text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525707/visualforce-convert-carriage-returns-to-html-line-breaks-in-a-long-text-field/6316962#6316962)

As you can see in that posting there is a custom controller for a Visualforce page that has tabbed content for Case. The only way to list CaseComments is with custom Apex. The controller performs a simple query to retrieve all the CaseComments for the current case.

I want to only show an "Edit" link if the current user has permission to edit the instance of a particular case comment.

I found a good blog about rendering components dynamically based on object level security here: 
http://forcearchitects.deliveredinnovation.com/2011/02/05/render-visualforce-components-dynamically-based-on-object-level-security/

Based on that posting I tried using

```
$ObjectType.CaseComment.updateable
```

As in the following:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!comments}" var="c">
    <tr>
    <td class="commentsActionColumn">
    <!-- open the case comment for edit -->
    <apex:outputLink title=""
        rendered="{!$ObjectType.CaseComment.updateable}" 
    value="/{!c.id}/e?parent_id={!c.parentId}&retURL=/apex/{!$CurrentPage.Name}%3Fid={!case.id}" style="font-weight:bold">Edit</apex:outputLink> 
    </td>
    <td>
    <!-- display the case comment formatted using the apex outputField -->
    <div class="commentTdClass">
    <apex:outputField value="{!c.commentbody}"></apex:outputField>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

Unfortunately, the test for updateable is on the Object level so it returns true on all CaseComments if the current user has permission to edit any CaseComment.

I need record level validation to only show the Edit action if the particular row can be modified by the current user.

Any ideas?

**Update**
As I reread my question I see that it wasn't as clear as it should be.

As I iterate over the set of CaseComments, for a given Case, I need to know if the current user can safely edit a particular CaseComment without seeing the "you don't have permission page". This test must be on a CaseComment by CaseComment record level basis because any given Case will have many CaseComments all contributed by different Users

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a couple of ways (I think).

If you want to go down a purely programmatic route then [look here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm) which discusses using the sharing object to allow record sharing with particular users or groups.

Otherwise, if possible you could use Roles and Hierarchy management to organise this in a way so that only people within a particular role of a particular level or above can see a record and access it?

Paul

Update:

Based upon your comment below I think you want to use apex sharing. If you look at [this useful developerforce wiki](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Using_Apex_Managed_Sharing_to_Create_Custom_Record_Sharing_Logic) you can see that you should access the sharing object to check whether or not the user has a record in this object to view the particular record instance. Something like:

```
MyObject__Share share1 = [Select ParentId, UserOrGroupId, AccessLevel from MyObject__Share where ParentId = :myrecordId And UserOrGroupId = :UserId];
if(share1 != null)
{ code to allow the record to be viewed}
else
{code to deny access}
```

I haven't tested or tried that so you will want to tweak it but that should be the general idea.

Paul

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have probably mislead you with the way I phrased my question (normal for me).  The problem is not with object level but with record level permissions. I don't want to create rules to share all CaseComments on a Case. I just want to know if the current user can safely edit the CaseComment without seeing the "you don't have permission page". This is on a CaseComment by CaseComment record level basis because any given Case will have many CaseComments all contributed by different Users.  Is this clearer?

Comment: Updated the answer, let me know if that helps. Its a new area for me I will be honest, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the below URL.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008w0gIAA

Looks like we can use something like below. however ihaven't tested yet.

```
SELECT RecordId, [HasReadAccess, HasEditAccess, HasAllAccess, MaxAccessLevel] FROM UserRecordAccess
WHERE UserId = [single ID]
AND RecordId = [single ID] 
//or Record IN [list of IDs]
```